# Why does my program that creates a stack using std::vector crash?

Tags: c++, stack

I am creating my own stack for my data structures class.  For our assignment we are using the assignment to convert a real-time infix equation into a postfix equation.
    I thought my program:
        took input
        determines if it was digit or number(operand)
            prints it out
        determines if input is operator (+,-,/,*)
            adds to stack or prints out, depending on stack precedence

Instead it prints out the operands as expect, but I get this error when I enter an operator

```
>.../dorun.sh line 33: 4136 Segmentation fault     <core dumped> sh "$<SHFILE>"


#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class DishWell{  
public:  
    char ReturnEnd(){  
        return Well.back();  
    }  
    void Push(char x){  
        Well.push_back(x);  
    }  
    void Pop(){  
        Well.pop_back();  
    }  
    bool IsEmpty(){  
        return Well.empty();  
    }  
private:  
    vector<char> Well;  
};   
#include <iostream>  
bool Precidence(char Input, char Stack){  
    int InputPrecidence,StackPrecidence;  
    switch (Input){  
        case '*':  
            InputPrecidence = 4;  
            break;
        case '/':
            InputPrecidence = 4;  
            break;  
        case '+':  
            InputPrecidence = 3;  
            break;  
        case '-':  
            InputPrecidence = 3;  
            break;  
        case '(':  
            InputPrecidence = 2;  
            break;  
        default:  
            InputPrecidence = 0;  
    }  
    switch (Stack){  
        case '*':  
            StackPrecidence = 4;  
            break;  
        case '/':  
            StackPrecidence = 4;  
            break;  
        case '+':  
            StackPrecidence = 3;  
            break;  
        case '-':  
            StackPrecidence = 3;  
            break;  
        case '(':  
            StackPrecidence = 2;  
            break;  
        default:  
            StackPrecidence = 0;  
    }  
    if(InputPrecidence>StackPrecidence) return true;  
    else return false;  
}  
int main(int argc, char** argv) {  
    DishWell DishTray;  
    char Input;  
    bool InputFlag;  
    InputFlag = true;  
    while(InputFlag){  
        cin>>Input;  
        if((((Input>='a'&&Input<='z')||(Input>='A'&&Input<='Z'))|| (Input>='0'&&Input<='9')))//If Digit or Number  
            cout<<Input;  
        if((Input=='*'||Input=='/'||Input=='+'||Input=='-')){//if operand  
            if(Precidence(Input,DishTray.ReturnEnd()))  
                DishTray.Push(Input);  
            else if(!Precidence(Input,DishTray.ReturnEnd()))  
                cout<<Input;  
        }  
        else if(!((((Input>='a'&&Input<='z')||(Input>='A'&&Input<='Z'))||    (Input>='0'&&Input<='9')))||((Input=='*'||Input=='/'||Input=='+'||Input=='-')))//if not digit/numer or operand  
            InputFlag = false;  
    }  
    while(!DishTray.IsEmpty()){  
        cout<<DishTray.ReturnEnd();  
        DishTray.Pop();  
    }  
    return 0;
```

My code is very length, I know, but I appreciate help. Especially any times for efficency or future coding.

Thanks again

P.S. Dr. Zemoudeh, this is your student Macaire

Comment: is it a must to read user input one by one, and calculate on the fly ?

Comment: What does dorun.sh do, and can you give us some sample input? I can't identify which line the error is on from the output you've given us - can you show us which line number the seg fault occurs on? Can you run this under a debugger and get a back trace? FYI, it's prec*e*dence with an 'e'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll expand on Rup's answer to answer the question you didn't ask, but is more important:  **How can I find out where my program is crashing?**

One way is to put `std::cout` or `printf` statements throughout your program.  Put a statement at the beginning of every function saying, "function x enter" and at the end saying, "function x exit".  Run your program and when it crashes, you'll see what function it's in.  At that point, you can add lines to print the contents of each variable to find out what's going wrong.

Another way is to use a debugger, like `gdb`.

First, compile your program with the `-g` switch to enable debugging information.

```
linux@linux-ubuntu:~/t$ g++ prog.cpp -o prog -g
```

Next, tell the debugger `gdb` to run your program.

```
linux@linux-ubuntu:~/t$ gdb ./prog
```

At the gdb prompt, type `run` to start your program.  I entered `4*(3+2)` and the program crashed `at prog.cpp:7`, which is the line `return Well.back();`.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/linux/t/prog 
4*(3+2)
4
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048d0b in DishWell::ReturnEnd (this=0xbffff460) at prog.cpp:7
7           return Well.back();
```

For more complex programs, you'll often need a list of all the functions that are currently being called.  You can get that information with `bt`, short for "backtrace".  In the following backtrace, you see that the function `main` (#1) is calling function `DishWell::ReturnEnd` (#0).  #0 is the current function because functions form a stack, where the current function is the top of the stack (offset 0 is the top).

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x08048d0b in DishWell::ReturnEnd (this=0xbffff460) at prog.cpp:7
#1  0x08048b35 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff534) at prog.cpp:75
(gdb)
```

With only these 2 commands (`run`, `bt`), you've solved 80% of the problem:  finding where your program has crashed.  If you stopped reading here, you should be able to solve the problem by adding print statements or asserts to see what the state of `Well` is and why `back()` is crashing your program.  But let's use `gdb` some more...

You can type `list` to see the source code around that line for more context without leaving the debugger.

```
(gdb) list
2   using namespace std;
3   
4   class DishWell{  
5   public:  
6       char ReturnEnd(){  
7           return Well.back();  
8       }  
9       void Push(char x){  
10          Well.push_back(x);  
11      }  
(gdb)
```

gdb can print variables and simple expressions.  Printing the value of `Well` here is not too helpful for the novice, because it's a complex data structure and not a simple variable.  But we can tell gdb to call a method on that variable...

```
(gdb) print Well.size()
$2 = 0
(gdb) print Well.empty()
$3 = true
```

Ah ha, `Well` is empty, and you've called `back()` on it.  When we look at some [good documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(C%2B%2B)) for `std::vector`, we see that you invoke undefined behavior, which in this case is a program crash.

Now look through your program and try to figure out why `Well` was empty when your program wasn't expecting it to be empty.  If you like `gdb`, read some tutorials on it and learn how to do things like set breakpoints, or single step.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your `while(InputFlag)` loop:

```
    if((Input=='*'||Input=='/'||Input=='+'||Input=='-')){//if operand  
        if(Precidence(Input,DishTray.ReturnEnd()))
```

The issue is that the first time through you're calling `DishTray.ReturnEnd()` on an empty vector. You need to check whether the vector is empty before calling `Precidence` and act appropriately, or return a 0 value from `ReturnEnd()` if the vector is empty, or something else. That all said I can't really see what you're trying to do here since you're piping the operands directly through to the output without referencing them against the stack in any way - is this really a correct implementation of the algorithm?

But you really need to learn how to debug this for yourself. You should really read `dorun.sh` to see how it's compiling the code, and you should find out how to use `gdb` or `dbx` or whatever debugger you have on your system to figure this out for yourself. If it's gdb, you probably want something like

```
 g++ -g mystack.cpp -o mystack
 gdb mystack
 run
 <enter input, e.g. 2+3+4+5>
 bt
```

Comment: Thank you, I will review your  answer & try it out.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your assignment is about implementing [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Since, it is a data structure assignment, if I were you, I would not use `std::vector`. Because, it is usually not allowed. You should implement ADT, with a `char stack[STACK_SIZE]` or dynamically with a link list approach.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't heard of Shunting-yard but I will definitely check the wiki out.

In this case we can use vector, probably because in a following lab we will also create our own vector. What is ADT that you recommend i implement?