# Segmentation fault when initializing memory for pointer to array passed to a function

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault

I am writing a function that creates a set of primes numbers less than the limit passed to it. For some reason, I am having trouble getting the memory-management right; I keep getting "Segmentation Fault: 11." Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getPrimes(int** primes, int* limit);

int main(void){
    int primeLimit = 99;
    int* primes;
    getPrimes(&primes, &primeLimit);

    //Do stuff

    free(primes);

    return 0;
}

void getPrimes(int** primes, int* limit){

    int multiplier; //Number used to multiply by to find numbers that do have factors
    int multiple; //Stores the current multiple
    int numPrimes = 0; //Number of primes (returned to caller)
    int count = 0;
    int* marked = (int*)malloc(*limit * sizeof(int)); //Initialize memory and sets it to 0
    memset(marked, 0, *limit);

    marked[0] = 1; //Set 0 and 1 to be not prime
    marked[1] = 1;

    for(int base = 2; base < *limit; base++){//Go through each number and mark all its multiples, start with 2
        if(!marked[base]){ //If base is already marked, its multiples are marked
            multiplier = 2; //Start multiple at 2
            multiple = base * multiplier; //Set first multiple for loop
            while(multiple < *limit){//Mark each multiple until limit reached
                marked[multiple] = 1;
                multiplier++;
                multiple = base * multiplier;
            }
        }
    }

    //Do a sweep to get the number of primes

    for(int num = 2; num < *limit; num++){//Go through each number and check if marked
        if(!marked[num]){ //Number is prime
            numPrimes++; //Increase count of primes if number is prime
        }
    }

    *limit = numPrimes; //update limit to the number of primes
    *primes = (int*)malloc(numPrimes * sizeof(int)); //Allocate memory for primes

    //Now actually put the primes in the array

    printf("Number of Primes: %d\n\n", numPrimes);

    for(int num = 2; num < *limit; num++){//Go through each number and check if marked
        printf("Num: %d, ", num); //Print it for debugging
        printf("Count: %d\n", count);
        if(!marked[num]){ //Number is prime
            *primes[count] = num; //Append to primes list (returned to caller)
            count++; //Increase count of primes if number is prime
        }
    }

    free(marked); //Free the memory used to mark multiples

    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  What line are you on when the debugger segfaults?

Comment: Here is an example of how you can debug this yourself:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4717073/19719

Comment: It won't trigger a segfault, but `memset(marked, 0, *limit*sizeof(int));` might be better.

Comment: In the second loop, `for(int num = 2; num < *limit; num++){`, `*limit` has changed, it is not the length of `marked` anymore. It could trigger a segfault if `numPrime` is higher than `*limit`...This is unlikely though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of your problem is :

```
*primes[count] = num;
```

It makes an attempt to reach `primes[count]` and it fails as soon as `count>0`.
To correct this :

```
(*primes)[count] = num;
```

There are some other points to get a correct result :

- To initialize `marker`, do  `memset(marked, 0, *limit*sizeof(int));`. The function `memset()` comes from `string.h` : it sets the first `*limit*sizeof(int)` [bytes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/)
- In the second loop, `for(int num = 2; num < *limit; num++){`, `*limit` has changed, it is not the length of `marked` anymore. To remove this issue the initial value of `*limit` may be stored in `formerlimit`.

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void getPrimes(int** primes, int* limit);

int main(void){
    int primeLimit = 99;
    int* primes;
    getPrimes(&primes, &primeLimit);

    //Do stuff

    free(primes);

    return 0;
}

void getPrimes(int** primes, int* limit){

    int multiplier; //Number used to multiply by to find numbers that do have factors
    int multiple; //Stores the current multiple
    int numPrimes = 0; //Number of primes (returned to caller)
    int count = 0;
    int formerlimit=*limit;
    int* marked = (int*)malloc(*limit * sizeof(int)); //Initialize memory and sets it to 0
    memset(marked, 0, *limit);

    marked[0] = 1; //Set 0 and 1 to be not prime
    marked[1] = 1;

    for(int base = 2; base < *limit; base++){//Go through each number and mark all its multiples, start with 2
        if(!marked[base]){ //If base is already marked, its multiples are marked
            multiplier = 2; //Start multiple at 2
            multiple = base * multiplier; //Set first multiple for loop
            while(multiple < *limit){//Mark each multiple until limit reached
                marked[multiple] = 1;
                multiplier++;
                multiple = base * multiplier;
            }
        }
    }

    //Do a sweep to get the number of primes

    for(int num = 2; num < *limit; num++){//Go through each number and check if marked
        if(!marked[num]){ //Number is prime
            numPrimes++; //Increase count of primes if number is prime
        }
    }

    *limit = numPrimes; //update limit to the number of primes
    *primes = (int*)malloc(numPrimes * sizeof(int)); //Allocate memory for primes

    //Now actually put the primes in the array

    printf("Number of Primes: %d\n\n", numPrimes);

    for(int num = 2; num < formerlimit; num++){//Go through each number and check if marked
        printf("Num: %d, ", num); //Print it for debugging
        printf("Count: %d\n", count);
        if(!marked[num]){ //Number is prime
            (*primes)[count] = num; //Append to primes list (returned to caller)
            count++; //Increase count of primes if number is prime
        }
    }

    free(marked); //Free the memory used to mark multiples

    return;
}
```

`multiplier` is not necessary, it may be changed for `multiple+=base;`

If it fails on high numbers, think about overflows.